# Reversed 'Attribute Starts With' selector in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Selector '`Attribute Starts With'` *selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string*, according to the documentation. I would like to to do the exact opposite thing - I would like to select those elements **whose value of a specified attribute is at the beginning of given string**.

Consider following example:

```
<a href="/about-us/">About us</a>
<a href="/products/">Products</a>
<a href="/contact/">Contact</a>
```

Current URL is `/products/some-catogory/sub-category/product/?x=y&z=x` and I want to highlight the second menu item. What's the best way to do it?

Comment: You want to use the current URL to identify which link in the navigation menu links to the current/'active' page? Or the link whose `href` attribute most-closely matches the current URL?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. The href value "/products/" is at the beginning of current URL so I want this link to be selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
var path = document.location.pathname;
$('a').filter(
    function(i,e){
        return $(this).attr('href').indexOf(path) == 0;
    }).addClass('highlight');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pYwzF/).

Where the `highlight` class-name defines, appropriately enough, the highlighting.

This is tested with the following HTML:

```
<a href="/about-us/">About us</a>
<a href="/products/">Products</a>
<a href="/_display/">_display</a>
<a href="/contact/">Contact</a>​
```

Bear in mind this is proofed on JS Fiddle, so it'll match the the third `a` element (since that's the one that matches.

Edited to offer a slightly more generic solution, in which you can match by a given directroy/subdirectory:

```
function directory(path) {
    if (!path) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var _tmp = path.split('/'),
            directories = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = _tmp.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (_tmp[i].length > 0 && _tmp[i].indexOf('?') == -1) {
                directories.push(_tmp[i]);
            }
        }
        return directories;
    }
}
// in the real world use:
// var path = document.location.pathname,
var path = '/products/some-catogory/sub-category/product/?x=y&z=x',
    dir = directory('/products/some-catogory/sub-category/product/?x=y&z=x')[0];
$('a').filter(
    function(i, e) {
        return $(this).attr('href').indexOf(dir) == 0 || $(this).attr('href').indexOf('/' + dir) == 0
    }).addClass('highlight');​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pYwzF/1/).

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problems. There is only one flaw - you mixed the order ;) `return (path.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) == 0)` this works for me...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do but you could select the second item with this:

```
a:contains("Products")
```

Comment: Sorry, I probably didn't explain clearly what I'm trying to achieve - see comments bellow the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:not` along with the 'Attribute Start With' selector to achieve this.

*For example:* `$('a:not([href^="whetever"])')`

See this **demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/XH7Ut/

Comment: This selects links whose href attribute doesn't start with "whatever". I need to select links whose href attribute is a prefix of "whatever". See the accepted answer.

Comment: Ok. I get it now. I way I understood is that you were looking for the exact opposite of starts-with selector and thus my answer. :-)